# Issues in storing a portion of an AJAX GET response (in JSON) into a string variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, getjson

I have a problem trying to store part of the result of a GET request via AJAX into a string variable.

Basically, I wanted to make it so a certain function that contains a GET request operation would return the result of that operation.

```
var count = 0;

$.getJSON("https://api.icndb.com/jokes/count", function(data){ 
    count = data.value+1;
    for (i = 1; i < count; i++){ 
        if (i != 1) {
            setTimeout(jokeGet, i*7500, i);
        }
        else {
            jokeGet(i);
        }
    }
});

function jokeGet(n) {
    var str = "";
    $.getJSON("https://api.icndb.com/jokes/" + n, function(data){
        if (data.type != "NoSuchQuoteException") {
            $(".joke").html(data.value.joke);
            str = data.value.joke;
        }
        else {
            count++;
        }
    });

    return str;
}
```

The API I'm making the request(s) to stores the information in JSON trees. Here are two examples of such trees:

```
{ "type": "success", "value": { "id": 1, "joke": "Chuck Norris uses ribbed condoms inside out, so he gets the pleasure.", "categories": ["explicit"] } }

{ "type": "NoSuchQuoteException", "value": "No quote with id=8." }
```

However, whenever I run the unit tests (via QUnit), it turns out that, in any and all cases, the `jokeGet()` function returns an empty string. Which is something that I find strange, since I would think that the `str = data.value.joke` line would have made it so the joke was stored in that variable `str`.

Apparently, because `str` always returns as an empty string, that is not the case. Any suggestions as to why this is?

**Update**

Considering that the goal of what I am doing right now isn't to get the program to work but to make unit tests to demonstrate that the program works, I have decided to include the "unit tests" file:

```
QUnit.test("cn_jokes", function(assert) {
    function joke(n, expected) {
        assert.equal(jokeGet(n), expected);
    }
    joke(1, "Chuck Norris uses ribbed condoms inside out, so he gets the pleasure.");
    joke(8, undefined);
    joke(163, "Ninjas want to grow up to be just like Chuck Norris. But usually they grow up just to be killed by Chuck Norris.");
    joke(221, "Chuck Norris is the only person to ever win a staring contest against Ray Charles and Stevie Wonder.");
    joke(352, "Chuck Norris doesn't see dead people. He makes people dead.");
    joke(502, "Chuck Norris insists on strongly-typed programming languages.");
    joke(526, "No one has ever pair-programmed with Chuck Norris and lived to tell about it.");
    joke(598, "Once Chuck Norris and Superman had a competition. The loser had to wear his underwear over his pants.");
});
```

As you can see, I would like to get the `jokeGet()` function, specifically, to return the joke value. Please let me know whether this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous; your code will continue to run while the request is made. Because of this, `str` is returned long before by the callback you pass to `getJSON` runs. You should probably have `jokeGet` take a callback function, and call it when the request is complete (passing `data.value.joke` as an argument):

```
function jokeGet(n, callback) {
    $.getJSON("https://api.icndb.com/jokes/" + n, function(data){
        if (data.type != "NoSuchQuoteException") {
            $(".joke").html(data.value.joke);
            if (callback !== undefined && callback !== null)
                callback(data.value.joke);
        }
        else {
            count++;
            if (callback !== undefined && callback !== null)
                callback(undefined); // not sure if you want undefined or "" in this case
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT: You can use asynchronous callbacks with QUnit. Just use `assert.async()`, as mentioned [here](https://qunitjs.com/cookbook/#asynchronous-callbacks):

```
QUnit.test("cn_jokes", function(assert) {
    var done = assert.async();
    var jokesDone = 0;
    var numJokes = 8; // make sure to change this if you add more
    function joke(n, expected) {
        jokeGet(n, function(j) {
            assert.equal(j, expected);
            if (++jokesDone == numJokes) done();
        }
    }
    joke(1, "Chuck Norris uses ribbed condoms inside out, so he gets the pleasure.");
    joke(8, undefined);
    joke(163, "Ninjas want to grow up to be just like Chuck Norris. But usually they grow up just to be killed by Chuck Norris.");
    joke(221, "Chuck Norris is the only person to ever win a staring contest against Ray Charles and Stevie Wonder.");
    joke(352, "Chuck Norris doesn't see dead people. He makes people dead.");
    joke(502, "Chuck Norris insists on strongly-typed programming languages.");
    joke(526, "No one has ever pair-programmed with Chuck Norris and lived to tell about it.");
    joke(598, "Once Chuck Norris and Superman had a competition. The loser had to wear his underwear over his pants.");
});
```

Comment: Is there no way to get the jokeGet() function itself to return the value?

Comment: @JMG No, not really. You _could_ make `jokeGet` return a `Promise` which you resolve with `data.value.joke` and call it in an `async` function with `await`. This could make your code look somewhat more structured, but using `await` seems overkill for something as simple as this, and IE doesn't have support for it.

Comment: Yay, that did it! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

try using the return statement inside the if block

```
if(condition){
return str;
} else {
return
}
```

I guess this behavious is due to the async nature of js , it returns value before the get request is complete

Comment: No avail. I'm guessing because of the function(data) inside jokeGet(). Using that strategy, the variable "str" is considered a variable that belongs not to jokeGet(), but to the inner function relevant to the ajax call.